# Inserting XML data into a table at certain location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm developing a simple TV guide for use in browsers.

My current HTML draws the table with the scheduled times and also displays the channel names on the left hand side

I would like to know what the best way to insert films into this HTML table at the correct times using my XML film data

I've been trying to load my XML data using the tutorial here

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table

And insert the data at appropriate part in table using this

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Heres my

HTML Code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>

   <!--HEADER CONTENT-->

   <head>
    <title>My website</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

    <div class="page-title">
        <p>TV Guide</p>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>


<!-- MAIN BODY -->

<body>

    <table class="tv-planner">
        <tr>
            <th class = "information">Channel</th>
            <th class="times">9AM</th>
            <th class="times">10AM</th>
            <th class="times">11AM</th>
            <th class="times">12PM</th>
            <th class="times">1PM</th>
            <th class="times">2PM</th>
            <th class="times">3PM</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class = "information">Channel 1</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class = "information">Channel 2</th>
        </tr>

                <tr>
            <th class = "information">Channel 4</th>
        </tr>

                <tr>
            <th class = "information">Sky One</th>
        </tr>

                <tr>
            <th class = "information">Channel Five</th>
        </tr>


    </table>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Update TV-guide</button>

    <script>

        function myFunction() {

            // Code to read XML file + insert into existing table 
        }

    </script>
```

XML code:

```
<MOVIE_DATA>

    <MOVIE>
        <movie_id="1">
        <channel_1>
            <name>Simpsons</name>
            <start_time>10.00am</start_time>
            <end_time>1.00pm</end_time>
        </sean_channel>
    </MOVIE>

    <MOVIE>
        <movie_id="2">
        <roger_channel>
            <name>Suits</name>
            <start_time>9.00am</start_time>
            <end_time>12.00pm</end_time>
        </roger_channel>
    </MOVIE>

    <MOVIE>
        <movie_id="3">
        <sean_channel>
            <name>Mighty Boosh</name>
            <start_time>1.00pm</start_time>
            <end_time>2.00pm</end_time>
        </sean_channel>
    </MOVIE>

</MOVIE_DATA>
```

CSS:

```
.main-area{
    font-style: italic;
}


.page-title{

    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: hoff voff blur #000;

}

.times{
    width: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FF0000;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    border: 1px solid black;

}

.tv-planner{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.information{
    width: 15%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;

}
```

Any advice on how I should approach this problem, and whether i'm onto the right idea with the resources i'm using would be really helpful

Thanks!

Comment: parse the xml the same way but insert rows instead of using `document.write` which will wipe out everything in the page after page has loaded

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to give each row a unique identifier equal to the channel name as appears in your XML (i.e. sean_channel ... ).

As you cycle through your XML data, locate the row using javascript/jquery and using insert HTML as you cycle through the hours of the day. If you columns start at 9AM, then you need to offset the show's duration, such that 10AM-11AM would mean the 2nd column.

For every hour you cycle through and duration the hour does not fall into the duration, use empty . Convert the XML data for time to an integer, such that 2.30pm becomes the 24h equivalent of 14.5. With this you can use simple math to calculate the offset. So if starting 9am then a duration of 11am start would be 11-9=2. The result 2 would relate to your counter as you cycle through, starting at 0 so 2 directly matches with the 3rd column (no adjustment needed to the counter).

All this is very simplistic and hopefully should be enough to get you started and possibly thinking about a more refined and complex solution like a cell being the duration between time markers, so cell headers should be left aligned to match beginning of a certain time duration. Going further you could relate 1 cell per 15min duration, and so on.